# Take only letters from string elements

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

I have a long list like this: `A = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23']`

How can I get only the letters part without numbers and make them another list?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [''.join([l for l in x if l.isalpha()]) for x in xs]
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

Comment: You don't need to make an intermediate list, str.join works on any iterable.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23']
>>> B = list(map(lambda x: ''.join([letter for letter in x if letter.isalpha()]), A))
>>> B
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

`filter()` would have been a better choice than `map()`:

```
>>> A = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23']
>>> B = [''.join(filter(str.isalpha, a)) for a in A]
>>> B
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

This, of course, is basically identical to @chrisaycock's answer.

If you'd like to eliminate duplicate entries, use a `set`:

```
>>> A = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23', 'ABCd 95']
>>> B = set(''.join(filter(str.isalpha, a)) for a in A)
>>> B
{'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk', 'ABCd'}
```

If you'd like to eliminate duplicate entries but you need to preserve the ordering of the original list, sort a set by index:

```
>>> A = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23', 'ABCd 95']
>>> B = [''.join(filter(str.isalpha, a)) for a in A]
>>> B
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk', 'ABCd']
>>> C = sorted(set(B), key=lambda x: B.index(x))
>>> C
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

or avoid an intermediate `list` and `set` by doing it manually:

```
>>> A = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23', 'ABCd 95']
>>> B = []
>>> for a in A:
...     b = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, a))
...     if b not in B:
...             B.append(b)
...
>>> B
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

Comment: Your solution is better than chrisaycock's answer, if only for the simple reason that in Python 3.x, filter returns an iterator instead of a string. (He's using an intermediate list instead of a generator) In Python 2.x, the advantage is pure elegance, you can simply do `filter(str.isalpha, s)` and it will automatically return a string without you having to join because filter does a smart type-check.

Comment: Thank you @TigerhawkT3, I think I will use this. But after that, I need only one string if there's the same word of it. Like, I need only 'ABCd' but there is 5 'ABCd' element in the B list that you wrote actually.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include solutions for removing duplicates, with and without preserving the original `list`'s order.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), this is quite simple!

```
>>> strings = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23']
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]+', '', s) for s in strings]
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

Want the numbers too?

```
>>> [re.sub(r'[^\d]+', '', s) for s in strings]
['123', '345', '23']
```

Comment: Much better than flattening the list of matches. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> values = ['ABCd 123', 'Efhgh 345', 'dhAsadjkhdk 23']

>>> [value.split()[0] for value in values]
['ABCd', 'Efhgh', 'dhAsadjkhdk']
```

Comment: This assumes a certain structure which hasn't been mentioned or confirmed and may be coincidental.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 need more test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to search for the groups of letters in the list:

```
words = map(lambda s: re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s), A)
words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(words))
```